# ListView disposes and recreates the State & RenderObject of all children

Tags: flutter

I'm dealing with videos inside a ListView and since the objects are getting unnecessarily disposed, it downloads the same video several times. The performance takes a bad hit because of that. Below is the code of list view. I have also tried Listview.builder and Listview but all exhibiting the same behavior.

```
ListView.custom(
      childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return VideoPlayer(
              id: snapshot.data[index]['url'],
            );
          },
          childCount: snapshot.data.length,
          findChildIndexCallback: (Key key) {
            final ValueKey valueKey = key;
            final String data = valueKey.value;
            return snapshot.data
                .indexWhere((element) => element['url'] == data);
          }),
      controller: controller,
    );
```

Comment: You shouldn't store important state in your ListView children, let alone resource-intensive media. Download and cache the videos outside of the Listview subtree, so that the children can easily access them on demand. Read about [destruction mitigation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Riwen, i used SliverChildListDelegate and AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin with every List item and it solved the problem.

Comment: If you have a limited number of children, then yeah, it is indeed a solution. However, if your list grows larger, you're likely to experience performance issues.